# How to find unique name/character from a list of names in R

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates, multiple-columns

I have a huge list of company names. As illustrated below, if name company is  ABBEYCREST.DEAD...10.10.14...ASK.PRICE, this means ABBEYCREST.DEAD...10.10.14... is name of company and ASK.PRICE is ASK Price data and when it ends with BID.PRICE is means its the BID PRICE data. I want to identify the company whose only one column name is avaiable in the dataframe. Actually I have a dataframe which has colum headers as illustrated below, implying each company should have 2 columns, if there are 4000 companies so there should be 8000 columns in my dataframe but I have 7999 ( although my dataframe has a date column but I exclude it when I count columns).

```
df<-AskBid

    ABBEYCREST.DEAD...10.10.14...ASK.PRICE
    ABBEYCREST.DEAD...10.10.14...BID.PRICE
    ABBOT.GROUP.DEAD...07.03.08...ASK.PRICE
    ABBOT.GROUP.DEAD...07.03.08...BID.PRICE
    ABERDEEN.ASSET.MAN..FULLY.PAID.23.09.05...ASK.PRICE
    ABERDEEN.ASSET.MAN..FULLY.PAID.23.09.05...BID.PRICE
    ABERDEEN.ASSET.MAN..NIL.PAID.23.09.05...ASK.PRICE
    ABERDEEN.ASSET.MAN..NIL.PAID.23.09.05...BID.PRICE
    ABERDEEN.FTBL.CLUB.DEAD...DEAD.04.08.03...ASK.PRICE
    ABERDEEN.FTBL.CLUB.DEAD...DEAD.04.08.03...BID.PRICE
    ABERTIS..IRS....BID.PRICE
    ABGENIX..IRS..DEAD...12.11.07...ASK.PRICE
    ABGENIX..IRS..DEAD...12.11.07...BID.PRICE
    ABLON.GROUP.DEAD...31.05.13...ASK.PRICE
    ABLON.GROUP.DEAD...31.05.13...BID.PRICE
    ACAMBIS.DEAD...25.09.08...ASK.PRICE
    ACAMBIS.DEAD...25.09.08...BID.PRICE
```

I want to find is

```
missing <- df
ABERTIS..IRS....BID.PRICE
```

I would really appreciate your help. This is causing problems in my estimations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the `ASK.PRICE` and `BID.PRICE` part and call `duplicated` twice (the second time on the reversed order):

```
cn <- readLines(textConnection(
"ABBEYCREST.DEAD...10.10.14...ASK.PRICE
ABBEYCREST.DEAD...10.10.14...BID.PRICE
ABBOT.GROUP.DEAD...07.03.08...ASK.PRICE
ABBOT.GROUP.DEAD...07.03.08...BID.PRICE
ABERDEEN.ASSET.MAN..FULLY.PAID.23.09.05...ASK.PRICE
ABERDEEN.ASSET.MAN..FULLY.PAID.23.09.05...BID.PRICE
ABERDEEN.ASSET.MAN..NIL.PAID.23.09.05...ASK.PRICE
ABERDEEN.ASSET.MAN..NIL.PAID.23.09.05...BID.PRICE
ABERDEEN.FTBL.CLUB.DEAD...DEAD.04.08.03...ASK.PRICE
ABERDEEN.FTBL.CLUB.DEAD...DEAD.04.08.03...BID.PRICE
ABERTIS..IRS....BID.PRICE
ABGENIX..IRS..DEAD...12.11.07...ASK.PRICE
ABGENIX..IRS..DEAD...12.11.07...BID.PRICE
ABLON.GROUP.DEAD...31.05.13...ASK.PRICE
ABLON.GROUP.DEAD...31.05.13...BID.PRICE
ACAMBIS.DEAD...25.09.08...ASK.PRICE
ACAMBIS.DEAD...25.09.08...BID.PRICE"))

## remove (ASK|BID).PRICE
cn.sub <- gsub("(ASK|BID)\\.PRICE$", "", cn)

cn[!(duplicated(cn.sub) | rev(duplicated(rev(cn.sub))))]
# [1] "ABERTIS..IRS....BID.PRICE"
```

Comment: Is it possible to know the name of the unique company that has been removed.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't really understand your question. The output of the code above is the unique column name (as you asked for in your original question). If `"ABERTIS..IRS....BID.PRICE"` is the only unique one, you know that `"ABERTIS..IRS....ASK.PRICE"` is missing.

Comment: Could I ran this code to find out uncommon(unique) column headers (company names) in two different dataframes?. But in those dataframes, company name ends with .S and in other dataframe the same company name ends with .TURNOVER.BY.VOLUME.

Comment: This is a similar problem: `cn <- c(colnames(df1), colnames(df2)); cn.sub <- gsub ("(\\.S|\\.TURNOVER.BY.VOLUME)$", "", cn); cn[!(duplicated(cn.sub) | rev(duplicated(rev(cn.sub))))]`.

Comment: I do realise it's bit a stretch.  Then delete those unique /uncommon out from the two dataframes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution assuming text is the column name in the data frame read in:

```
library(dplyr)
df$text <- gsub(("(ASK|BID)", "", df$text)
df %>% group_by(text) %>% filter(n() != 2)
```